# Public instance methods

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = (function(){

    var c = function() {
        c.onCreate(this);
    };

    c.prototype = {
        bar: function() {
            console.log('bar');
        }
    };

    c.onCreate = function(){};

    return c;

})();


foo.onCreate = function(instance){
    console.log('new instance of foo created', instance);
};

var f = new foo();
```

Is it possible to create a public instance method of `onCreate`, instead of having it as a static method? If so, would I declare it inside the constructor function, or on the `foo` prototype?

http://jsfiddle.net/LtTam/

Just to elaborate, I would like to call `f.onCreate` on each instance, instead of calling a generic `foo.onCreate`.

Comment: What do you mean by `public instance method` and `static method`? Sorry, I get confused when it comes to javascript.

Comment: @thefourtheye I want to change `foo.onCreate` to `f.onCreate`. In other words, access the method on each instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
var foo = function(){};

foo.prototype.onCreate = function() {
    console.log("onCreate called");
};
```

**Method 2**

```
var foo = function() {
    var actualObject = {};
    actualObject.onCreate = function() {
        console.log("onCreate called");
    }
    return actualObject;
}
```

**Sample Tests:**

```
var f = new foo();
f.onCreate();
var g = new foo();
g.onCreate();
```

**Output**

```
onCreate called
onCreate called
```

**Edit:** With callback

**Method1**

```
var foo = function(){
    this.onCreate();
};

foo.prototype.onCreate = function() {
    console.log("onCreate executed");
};
```

**Method2**

```
var foo = function() {
    var actualObject = {};
    actualObject.onCreate = function() {
        console.log("onCreate executed");
    }
    actualObject.onCreate();

    return actualObject;
}
```

**EDIT:** A simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/fvTBE/

Comment: I want a callback when a new instance is called, not simply call an onCreate-method myself.

Comment: @Johan Updated my solution. Please check now.

Comment: The "new" method1 is closer to what I need. But still, how would you call it on an actual instance? Feel free to add a fiddle

Comment: @Johan Added a demo fiddle. Please check.

Comment: There is still no callback method on the `f` instance

Comment: What exactly you mean by callback method? In javascript, normally callback refers to passing a function as a parameter, which will be called explicitly when the called function completes execution. Is that what you want?

Comment: `var f = new foo(); f.onCreate(function(){ console.log('new instance'); });` That's what I'm after.

Comment: So you want to be able to call `onCreate` explicitly with a callback function and not to be called during object construction?

Comment: I want a callback which is triggered when the instance is created. Right now I've solved it with resolving a defferred object. I guess that'll do. I'll accept this for the effort. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Johan :) I would like to see the solution. Could you please update the question with the latest code?

Comment: Looks like I need to learn jQuery,Deferred and promises to understand this... ;)

Comment: It's really useful. Mostly for async stuff like ajax and web workers.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are asking.

Removed the static onCreate to become a public member Create(Public instance methods can also be created using prototype). Added a private member for the class also. Private member can only be invoked internally.
Read this [article](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS.html) for more details

```
var foo = function(){

    function privateMember(){
        console.log('Private Member');
    };

    return {
        create : function(){
            privateMember();
            console.log('Public Member');
        }
    };

};
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not what I'm asking for. Hopefully my comment above will make it clearer.